# Macro to remove duplicate rows in Excel sheet not working

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a macro which is part of a larger code. It is designed to remove duplicates from the sheet Confirmed Lays once all the data is copied into it. Unfortunately this part of the overall code does not work. Can anyone tell me what it is which is stopping it or how to fix it?

The sheet has columns A - X and I need the macro to remove any rows which are duplicates

When I have done this duplicate removal manually, the only columns I have bothered matching are A, B & H, as when those 3 match, the row is a duplicate.

Here is the code

```
Sub FinishUP()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Worksheets("Criteria").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Worksheets("Confirmed Lays").Activate
    Range("a:x").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

No need to activate the sheet (unless it's intentional)

And restrict the columns: array to just the column numbers you need them to match the duplicates

EDIT: In order to work with just the range with data, find the last row

**Code:**

```
Public Sub FinishUP()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Assuming the target sheet is in the same workbook that's calling the macro
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Confirmed Lays")

    ' Find last row
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Define the range to remove the duplicates from
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A1:X" & lastRow)

    ' Turn off alerts if you're going to do something that requires it
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    targetRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 8), Header:=xlYes

    ' DoSomething else?

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Try it, and let me know if it works.

Comment: cheers Ricardo. For some reason it removes some duplicates and leaves many others still in tact, so not sure why that is. I have checked those duplicate entries and A, B & H are identical
`04/03/2020 15:20 10 77.78 95.56 Catterick 4 Ilaya
04/03/2020 15:20 10 77.78 95.56 Catterick 4 Zoutoise
04/03/2020 15:20 10 77.78 95.56 Catterick 4 Ilaya
04/03/2020 15:20 10 77.78 95.56 Catterick 4 Zoutoise
04/03/2020 15:30 6 69.7 100 Lingfield 5 London Arch
04/03/2020 15:30 6 69.7 100 Lingfield 5 London Arch
`
Ilaya, Zoutouse & London Arch are all duplicates. I am Excel for Mac; make a difference?

Comment: Theorically no, and if it works manually, couldn't tell what's going on.